# Looking for an Ubuntu firewall script that will autoblock ips who scan ports

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

When someone tries to a blacklisted port, I'd like that IP address to be blocked at the firewall, for everything.  Even port 80.
Essentially I have a webserver, and see folks walking through ports to see what's available.  Obviously, they're up to no good and I'd like to slam the door on them. 
Is there a script that can do this?  Even if it's cron based, that's fine...

Comment: This is probably a question for ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for [psad](http://cipherdyne.org/psad/).

> psad is a collection of three
>   lightweight system daemons (two main
>   daemons and one helper daemon) that
>   run on Linux machines and analyze
>   iptables log messages to detect port
>   scans and other suspicious traffic. A
>   typical deployment is to run psad on
>   the iptables firewall where it has the
>   fastest access to log data.

[image]

And here is a great tutorial on [Detecting And Blocking Port Scan Attacks In Real Time](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-detect-port-scan-attacks/).